# ffmpeg kills python kernel upon completion of operation

Tags: python, ffmpeg, jupyter-notebook, kernel

I run the following prompt with `os.system(prompth)` in Python

```
ffmpeg -framerate {framerate} -i 'video-demo-frames/%d.ppm' -i temp-audio/audio.aac -shortest -c:v libx264 -r {framerate} -pix_fmt yuv420p {output}
```

`ffmpeg` creates the video from the frames and also does add the audio correctly. But upon the completion of the process it seems to kill my python kernel.

Some sources over the internet says that it is caused by the large size of my pictures and video, but i dont know whether that is true. What is the reason of this problem and how can ı solve it?